# Will program run with newer version of Qt?

Tags: qt, compatibility

I have a program that I need to edit that was developed with Qt version 5.0.1. Will the program still work correctly if I just grab the newest version and edit the program with that? Or am I better off getting the old version from the Qt archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt 5 is not 100% compatible with previous versions, so probably you will have to make some migration stuff. This little [transition guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) is your friend!

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was after